# How to translate “Be there or be square”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En voulant annoncer au monde entier ma soirée, j’ai voulu traduire “Be there or be square” en français mais je ne trouve pas d’équivalent. Une idée ?

Answer (score 11):

Une traduction possible (tirée de Men In Black ;) ) pour cette expression est :

> Soit tu viens, soit tu vaux rien

Comment: C'est surtout le traducteur qu'il faudrait référencer.

Comment: pas mal. J’ai l’impression que toutes ces phrases toutes faites sonnent marketting de toute façon, mais celle-là me plaît.